# Why is my Quickbook App getting error code 5020 Permission

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

My app is able to use the Quickbook online API to query customers like this:
`$this->dataService->Query("select * from Customer where DisplayName='{$displayName}'");`

but when I try query existing accounts like this:
`$this->dataService->Query("select * from Account where AccountType='{$accountType}' and AccountSubType='{$accountSubType}'");`

I get the following error:
`Permission Denied Error : You do not have the access rights to use this feature. Missing permission on Account to Read`

This works great when using sandbox company but it fails on product.

How can I add the missing permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime, I receive support from the developers at Quickbook and the error is caused by the plan we have.

Look here for more details: https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/5020-Permission-Denied-Error